# Is the Higgs VEV unnatural?

Tags: standard-model, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model, fine-tuning

Is there some way to argue that the Higgs VEV is unnatural, without even bringing up the Higgs boson mass? For example, can one show that the Higgs vev receives large corrections from new physics? The literature on renormalizing the Higgs vev doesn't seem to talk about this (or maybe I missed that part).

Comment: Might be interested in [Bian 2013](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.88.056022).